# How can I override parental controls on linksys

Tags: parental-controls

My son has figured out how to override the linksys internet pause on the router. How do I fix that

Comment: looking at the parental controls options, there appear to be a number of ways that the feature might not work properly, and I have a hunch that it uses DNS lookups to provide the blocking/pausing. so your child might: change from Wifi to wired interenet, which the router sees as a different device that does not have your policies, change the DNS server for their device to one that isn't the router, or use services online to modify the url of the target so that the router doesn't recognize it as a url that needs be blocked. https://www.linksys.com/gb/support-article/?articleNum=317707

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Take  your son's devices away and teach him better decision making. There may be technical ways to better block their access, but this is a very broad topic and it is likely, given the evidence we have, that your son will find more ways to circumvent your controls. This is, at its core, a human problem that you are looking for a technical solution to. I empathize. I have children of my own and have parental controls, but I am trying to teach my kids how to make good decisions rather than simply controlling their behavior by external means.

Answer (score 0):

Take your son's devices away and teach him better decision making.

There may be technical ways to better block their access, but this is a very broad topic and it is likely, given the evidence we have, that your son will find more ways to circumvent your controls. This is, at its core, a human problem that you are looking for a technical solution to.

I empathize: I have children of my own and have parental controls, but I am trying to teach my kids how to make good decisions rather than simply controlling their behavior by external means.